# Formatted string literals grammar

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

In Python official document [2.4.3. Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) the following grammar is defined:

```
f_string          ::=  (literal_char | "{{" | "}}" | replacement_field)*
```

Can someone explain why there are two curly braces here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained immediately below the grammar definition:

> The parts of the string outside curly braces are treated literally, except that any doubled curly braces '{{' or '}}' are replaced with the corresponding single curly brace.

This is so that you can "escape" the braces if you want literal braces to appear. As an example:

```
>>> print(f"braces look like {{this}}")
braces look like {this}
```